# Collapse pandas dataframe based on values of row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
user cat  state
u1   cat1 Y
u1   cat1 N
u1   cat2 Y
u1   cat2 Y
u1   cat3 N
u1   cat3 N
u2   cat1 Y
u2   cat1 N
```

How would I collapse the rows so to the state 'Y' for a (user, cat) pair as long as one of those pairs is 'Y', and 'N' otherwise?

Result I'm looking for:

```
user cat  state
u1   cat1 Y
u1   cat2 Y
u1   cat3 N
u2   cat1 Y
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['user', 'cat'], as_index=False).max()` ?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user','cat'], keep='first')`

Answer (score 0):

You can `drop_duplicates` and then `groupby` to ensure at most one Y row and one N row for each (user, cat) subgroup. Then you can check this subgroup to see if a 'Y' exists. The `reset_index` lets you rename the new column from the groupby back to 'state'.

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['user', 'cat']).apply(lambda x: 'Y' if x['state'].eq('Y').any() else 'N').reset_index(name='state')
```

This produces the expected output:

```
>>> print(new_df)
  user   cat state
0   u1  cat1     Y
1   u1  cat2     Y
2   u1  cat3     N
3   u2  cat1     Y
```